# iOS app name expiry and details

Tags: ios, app-store

One of my app was rejected in iTunes connect and it's getting close to 4 months(120 days) app upload limit.

Would Apple delete the app name as per its guidelines of 120 days?

Even though we have delivered a binary, we have not delivered an approved one. It would take a week to make the changes to ensure that it gets approved but we got only 2 days remaining out of 120 days grace period.

So, should we upload a binary immediately and get it approved(it takes few days minimum and we have no control) before expiry date or having been rejected already makes the "app name expiry" clock stop?

Note: You may never know what is the reason of app being rejected and the delay of 120 day period unless you are involved.  Anyways, Please kindly stick to my question and try to answer directly as to the procedures of app store as you know.

The question is "My app would expire in 2 days and we already have an app uploaded thats rejected. Does it mean we still can keep the app name after 2 days which would be 120th day of our app name expiry date because our app was already processed and rejected or is the 120 day time period for having the app approved for version 1.0, NOT uploading the app binary ALONE?"

Comment: Sounds like you need professional help to get your app approved in a short period of time. Average **Review** time (for all apps I have submitted) has been 9 days, with 0 rejections. 

Maybe you can explain more on what you mean by *"It would take a week to make the changes to ensure that it gets approved"*

Comment: @WrightsCS It isn't that easy. I am struggling with the Apple Review Team right now with an app which does something which is similar to lots of other apps and still it was rejected. I don't want to say the reason. I just wanted to point out that it's not always that easy.

Comment: Thanks for taking time...but you never know what is the reason unless you are involved. Anyways, Please kindly stick to my question and try to answer directly.

Comment: @user859375 thats where you come in and explain your situation thoroughly, to help us better understand the entire situation.

Comment: @WrightsCS Yes, True; thanks for your time. But doesn't my question asked in my original post take care of that already? "So, should we upload a binary immediately and get it approved(it takes few days minimum and we have no control) before expiry date or having been rejected already makes the "app name expiry" clock stop?"

Comment: If the app doesn't get approved, the name will expire anyway. You can always just create a new app name if it does not get approved.

Comment: @WrightsCS are you sure it will expire? If I have 3 days remaining and I submit an application, that will be rejected, does this mean I will loose the app name?   
I've read in http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/business-legal-app-store/96332-app-name-120-day-extension.html that the time will be reset once I submit binary.

Comment: What is the limit for App name reservation in iTunes now?